Unable to load FDO Provider library 'ShpProvider.dll'; (Null)
One of our interns is having trouble loading shapefiles in AutoCAD2023 Civil 3D. When trying to add a shapefile to a layout he receives the following error: Unable to load the FDO Provider Library 'ShpProvider.dll';(null). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling AutoCAD but still got the same error. The dll is present on the machine. Is this related to a permissions issue with the "FDO" folder or could there something else going on?
